# Doesn't get date from string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdateformatter

I have a string which contains a date. I'm trying to get the date from string but i didn't find right format.
This is the string:

```
NSString *lastModified=@"Thu, 07 Jan 2016 07:49:17 GMT";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss %Z"];
NSDate *lastDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:lastModified];
```

`lastDate` is always nil. 
Any help? Thank you!

EDIT!
I don't know if it is important but the date is taked from Head of an `NSUrl`

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:imageUrl];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue new] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

NSString *lastModified = [[httpResponse allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"];
```

I get `Head` from a `NSUrl` and need to check date of `Last-Modified` and compare with my date from database.

Here is httpResponse:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x15d00800> { URL: url } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 60065;
    "Content-Type" = "image/png";
    Date = "Thu, 07 Jan 2016 08:27:50 GMT";
    Etag = "\"568d4c77-eaa1\"";
    "Last-Modified" = "Wed, 06 Jan 2016 17:18:47 GMT";
    Server = nginx;
    "X-Powered-By" = PleskLin;
} }
```

That is all information i have.

Comment: try `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];`

Comment: u can try this also EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'

Comment: what components you need in your lastDate, for instance like date, month, year, etc.?

Comment: All components. Date and Time. I need to compare with another date with same format

Comment: @GabyFitcal - Use this in dateFormat @"eee, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z" and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: @nikhil84 No, is not working

Comment: Is something actually returned from `objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"`and put into `lastModified`?

Comment: @Popeye yes : (lldb) po lastModified
Wed, 06 Jan 2016 17:18:47 GMT

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
NSString *lastModified= @"Thu, 07 Jan 2016 07:49:17 GMT";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EE, dd LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss zz"];
NSDate *lastDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:lastModified];
```

**Edit:** Keep in mind, that NSDate is in UTC. (not GMT)

Comment: So long-story-short, `%Z` should be `Z`?

Comment: @brunobasas for me to. That why i am asking. I don't know why didn't work.

Comment: @GabyFitcal This works for me when using the rest of your code you have supplied

Comment: @"EE, dd LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss zz" is better.

Comment: first of all check if the `lastModified`is not nil before you parse it with the `NSDateFormatter`

Answer (score 1):

try with:
`[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];`